# Animations control in a pivot app (WP7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pivot, storyboard, windows-phone

I created a pivot in Xaml. The pivot has 4 items.

On every pivot there is a storyboard animation created by following code:

```
    {  
        var myStoryBoard = new Storyboard();  
        myStoryBoard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        var animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames(); 

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, myAnim1);  
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Source"));  

        myStoryBoard.Children.Add(animation);  

        // try to catch my images autmatically 

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)  
        {  
           var keyframe = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  
           {  
              KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(750 * i)),
              Value = String.Format("/Images/img_{0:D2}.jpg", i)  
           };  

            animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyframe); 
        }  
        Resources.Add("myAnimation", storyboard);         }
```

How can I set the Begin of the Storyboard to start only if the pivot item is selected, while all other Storyboards are not playing?

I tried to set it with `Pivot_SelectionChanged();` but without success.

Comment: corrected code as I written right now

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to create all storyboards in the loading method of your page and then show or hide the storyboard.

> ```
>     public MainPage()
>     {
>         // Create storyboard1
>         // create storyboard2 ...
>     }
> ```

Then with the Pivot_SelectionChanged method show or hide you storyboard

> ```
>     private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         switch (((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex)
>         {
>             case 0:
>                 storyboard1.Begin();
>                 storyboard2.Stop();
>                 break;
>             case 1:
>                 storyboard2.Begin();
>                 storyboard1.Stop();
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I tried this as shown above, but in the SelectionChanged method my Storyboards cannot get recognized...

Comment: You have to declare your Storyboard before. 
`Storyboard story1;
public MainPage()
    {
        story1 = new Storyboard(); ....
    }`
...
Like that you can use your storyboard everywhere and if you work with xaml, just add an x-name to your storyboard.

Comment: I had named them double (within Code Behind and my Xaml). Now I named them only in Xaml. Works like a charm. Performance of the pivot is now as it should be. Many Thx for your help and support!